# dropdownlist control in detailsview to database

Tags: database, ms-access, drop-down-menu, detailsview

I have a detailsview which is used for inserting new records to the GRIDVIEW. DetailsView has 3 bound fields and one template field. The template field has a dropdownlist control.

When I click insert, all the fields should be entered into the database. Bound fields get inserted, but I have problem with the dropdownlist control. I tried writing this code especially for dropdownlist in "INSERT" click event

protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        DropDownList ddl = null;
        ddl = new DropDownList();

        RateCenters rate = null;
        rate = new RateCenters();

        rate.statename = ddl.Text;

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@State/Province_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = statename;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

I am getting this error : **Parameter [State/Province_name] has no default value.**

Kindly help me to solve this issue

regards,
Arjun

Comment: What about the size/length of the varchar?

Comment: my problem here is "statename" is seem to be null during the run...

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be using rate.statename

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@State/Province_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rate.statename;
```